# Syntax error in sqlite query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am always getting this error.I think query is allright.What is problem?

**"Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error: , while compiling: create table Messages(_id integer , msgdesc text ,date timestamp  not null, createdby integer not null, to integer not null);
"**

This is my code:

```
public class ContactListDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MobileMerch";

// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String CREATE_MERCH  = "create table Merchendiser" +
        "(_id integer primary key, name text not null,surname text not null,username text not null);";

// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String CREATE_MESSAGES = "create table Messages" +
        "(_id integer , msgdesc text ,date timestamp  not null, createdby integer not null, to integer not null);";



public ContactListDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}    

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_MERCH);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES);


}
```

Comment: maybe "to" is reserved name?

Comment: i try my sql statements in the console and edit them in notepad++. this shows me what words are reserved and so i bypass program crashes and other bugs that takes some time to debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TO` is a reserved word. Either rename your column (recommended) or escape it by enclosing it in double-quotes (e.g. `"to"`).

See also: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html